# Difference between Site.Url , Web.Url and Site.RootWeb

Tags: sharepoint-server, url

I am new in SharePoint and I want to know the difference between `SPContext.Current.Site.Url, SPContext.Current.Web.Url and SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb` ?

Please help me to know the difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SPContext.Current.Site.Url** --> It will give the root site URL i.e. site collection URL.
**SPContext.Current.Web.Url** --> It will give the current web site url.
**SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb** --> An SPWeb object that represents the root Web site.

Answer (score 1):

As you may be aware, the typical structure is a site collection with one or more sites (webs) underneath, spread across multiple levels/tiers.

Sometimes the term **site** is used interchangeably (verbally) to refer to any given website, but in SharePoint, site and web are different objects.

The root site of your site collection will be your site collection's **root web**.

e.g. if you are located in the root site, then Current Web and Root Web will be equivalent in that context.

You'll want to use **Site** or **Web** depending on what you want to do, since each has its own methods and properties, e.g. get the url of the site collection VS get the url of the specific (web)site.

I guess `SPContext.Current.Web.Url` is the most typical property that you can use to grab the url of the current site, similar to [SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.serverrelativeurl.aspx), which is allows you to get away without specifying the domain, so I'd use that instead if possible.

example:

http://contoso.com/sitea/siteb

tests using javascript console:

_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl --> "/"

_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl --> "/sitea/siteb"

I guess this can be confusing at first, so I hope I did a decent job at explaining it.